# Foreign key mapping RESTKIT Core Data between two end point results

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, restkit

Is there any possibilities to join two end point results using foreign key.

```
End Point 1 :
{"series":[{"id":2,"name":"My Series","role":"student","student_id":15,"instructor_ids":[13],"sequential":false,"series_id":1,"user_assignment_ids":[3,4]}]} 

End Point 2 :
{"Assignments":[{ "id":3,"Name":"Assignment1", "seriesID":2},{ "id":4,"Name":"Assignment1","seriesID":2},{ "id":6,"Name":"Assignment1","seriesID":null}]}
```

In above two end point I have foreign key "user_assignment_ids".

```
@class UserAssignment;
@interface UserSeries : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * role;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sequential;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * seriesID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * studentID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id userAssignmentIDS;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *userAssignment;
@end

@interface UserSeries (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addUserAssignmentObject:(UserAssignment *)value;
- (void)removeUserAssignmentObject:(UserAssignment *)value;
- (void)addUserAssignment:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeUserAssignment:(NSSet *)values;

@end

@class UserSeries;

@interface UserAssignment : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * assignmentID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * seriesID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserSeries *userSeries;

@end
```

Can any one tell me the possible way to make two end point join using foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `RKConnectionDescription` to perform foreign key mappings. There are a number of examples and guidance on the docs page [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html).

Comment: Yes I referred those documents. In my scenario there are two different end points and two different result. How do I call those two  service in one call?

Comment: You can't do that. You could run both concurrently but the foreign key linking wouldn't be guaranteed. Run them sequentially or get the request / JSON response changed so they aren't 2 different requests.

Comment: So you are saying that I need to keep both result in One end point right?

Comment: That is one option. The other is to run the Series request first, then when it is saved you run the Assignments requests. Either the foreign key information needs to be saved before you try to use it or it needs to be all in the same response.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this kind of sequential call of two different service with foreign key, that would be great for me. :)

Comment: It is nothing special, just make the first call and then start the second call in the completion block of the first.

Comment: So Restkit will handle first call response mapping with second call response then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34689/discussion-between-wain-and-ganesh)

Comment: Do we need to store the results in Coredata so that we can join two  response?.... Can you please validate my code which I sent?